# Alternative to ASP.NET drop down list

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, webforms, controls

Regardless of what I do or try drop down list isn't just working,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drop1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" enabledviewstate="true" OnClick="Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

bind it here,

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindDropDownList();
            }
            //drop1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
```

and here's method, which never triggers (I use break point to check)

```
protected void Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //checkboxlist1.Items.Add("hahahha");
}
```

**Is there any alternative ?????????? I need to populate the Drop down list using,**

```
 using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), SelectCommand()))
            {
                System.Data.DataView dv = (System.Data.DataView)ds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                if (dv.Count > 0)
                {
                    drop1.DataSource = ds;
                    drop1.DataTextField = "UserName";
                    drop1.DataBind();
                    drop1.Items.Insert(0, "Please select a Username ");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Click` event defined for `DropDownList`. The event to use is [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drop1" runat="server"
                  AutoPostBack="true"
                  EnabledViewState="true"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead `OnSelectedIndexChanged` you typed `OnClick`

declare dropdownlist as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drop1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" enabledviewstate="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No Onclick event present for Dropdownlist use OnSelectedIndexChanged event for Dropdownlist.